# Jenkins powershell command not working

Tags: powershell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to use the following command:

```
powershell 'Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.Path -like "*mypath*" } | Stop-Process'
```

it works running it directly on the jenkins machine powershell, but not from the pipeline. Not sure if I have to escape a symbol but I tried some and didn't work either.

I need to use this command instead taskkill to be able to differenciate 2 instance of the same service running on different directories.

Comment: Seems the issue is related to not running powershell as administrator even if my Jenkins user is administrator type. I am still looking how to run a command as admin

Comment: You're using the cmd parser when you run that command.  Cmd doesn't recognize single-quotes.  Swap your single & double quotes and it should work.

Comment: I am trying `powershell 'Get-Process -name servers | Select-Object *'` to see all the data.. seems the command is executed as non-admin even if the jenkins service is using an Administrator account to run. If I run that command as admin I can see the Path property, if I run without admin, Path is empty. Is there a way to run this as admin from the jenkins pipeline?

Comment: That's a different question, but yes, you can use `Start-Process -FilePath powershell -ArgumentList 'array','o','args' -Verb runas`

Comment: but that's to run a file? I am using https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/07/26/powershell-pipeline/ as it is a 1 line command. Any way to achieve it with that?

Comment: If your process isn't already running with an elevated token (runas, etc.), you cannot self-elevate.  That goes against the entire Windows' security model.